# Pattern for apostrophe inside quotes

Tags: regex

I am looking for a pattern that can find apostrophes that are inside single quotes. For example the text

Foo 'can't' bar 'don't'

I want to find and replace the apostrophe in can't and don't, but I don't want to find the single quotes

I have tried something like

```
(.*)'(.*)'(.*)'
```

and apply the replace on the second matching group. But for text that has 2 words with apostrophes this pattern won't work.

Edit: to clarify the text could have single quotes with no apostrophes inside them, which should be preserved as is. For example

'foo' 'can't' bar 'don't'

I am still looking for only apostrophes, so the single quotes around foo should not match

Comment: Try [`\b'\b`](https://regex101.com/r/fE5mU2/1)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to require "word" characters to appear before and after a `'` symbol, and it can be done with a word boundary:

```
\b'\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE5mU2/1)

To only match the quote inside *letters* use

```
(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})
(?<=[[:alpha:]])'(?=[[:alpha:]])
(?U)(?<=\p{Alpha})'(?=\p{Alpha})  # Java, double the backslashes in the string literal
```

Or ASCII only

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
'[^']+'\s|'[^']+(')[^' ]+'
```

it will return 3 matches, and if capture group 1 participated in the word, it will be the apostrophe in the word:

- 'foo'
- 'can`'`t'
- 'don`'`t'

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE1iY7/1)

How it works:

- `'[^']+'\s`

  - `'` match an apostrophe
  - `[^']+` followed by at least one character that isn't an apostrophe
  - `'` followed by an apostrophe
  - `\s` followed by a space
- `|` or
- `'[^']+(')[^' ]+'`

  - `'` match an apostrophe
  - `[^']+` followed by at least one character that isn't an apostrophe
  - `(')` followed by an apostrophe, and capture it in capture group 1
  - `[^' ]+` followed by at least one character that is not an apostrophe or a space
  - `'` followed by an apostrophe