# Regex for escape apostrophe(single quote) in word with single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such a word written within single quotes:

`'Macy's'`

I need to escape apostrophe(or single quote if used instead) in the word. The regex that I have escape all single quotes in the word. I detect word inside single quotes and try to escape apostrophe(single quote) but all quotes are escaped:

```
if (word.match(/'(.*?)'/g)) {
   return `'${item.replace(/'/g, "\\'")}'`;
 }
```

so output is `'\'Macys\''` but I need it to be `'Macy\'s'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350169/3832970

Comment: this is not js but java

Comment: I need javascript answer and I didn't find any

Comment: Are you going to use this in a SQL-query?

Comment: no, I just need to escape it

Comment: So, `s.replace(/\b'\b/g, "\\'")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is what I'm looking for. Thanks.